# Round ScrollViewer in XAML

Tags: c#, xaml, win-universal-app

What I need is a rounded Scrollviewer. I tried to put it inside a Border with corner radius:

```
<Border Height="160" Width="160" CornerRadius="80" BorderThickness="5" BorderBrush="Red">
    <ScrollViewer Style="{StaticResource ZoomViewer>
        <Image Source="Assets/img1.jpg"/>
    </ScrollViewer>
</Border>
```

but the result shows that it doesn't work this way:

[image]

so how can I make it round?

Answer (score 2):

You should be using an `ImageBrush` like this as the `Background` of the `Border`, and then wrap the `Border` within a `ScrollViewer`.

```
<ScrollViewer Style="{StaticResource ZoomViewer>
    <Border Height="160"
            Width="160"
            CornerRadius="80"
            BorderThickness="5"
            BorderBrush="Red">
        <Border.Background>
            <ImageBrush ImageSource="Assets/img1.jpg" />
        </Border.Background>
    </Border>
</ScrollViewer>
```

Comment: That's not what I wanted. I wanted a part of an image rounded, not a zoomed round image. I made it as a sqaure for now